# How to access property of class instance passed to the constructor of another class

Tags: ruby, constructor

coming from the .net world and making my very first steps in Ruby. This should be pretty straightforward but still I am missing something:

```
class TestClass

  def initialize(foo_class)
    puts foo_class.number
  end
end


class FooClass
  @number = 3

  attr_accessor :number
end

foo_class = FooClass.new
test_class = TestClass.new(foo_class)
```

I would expect the number 3 to show up in the output but instead it's null.
But I have defined **@number** with just one **@** to make sure it's an instance variable, so it should be attached to the instance I am passing to the constructor of **TestClass**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance variables belong to instances. That’s why they are called instance variables. You have two instance variables here, both of which are called `@number`, which belong to two different instances.

One belongs to `FooClass`. This one is initialized to `3`. Another one belongs to `foo_class`. This one is never assigned to, hence it is uninitialized and thus evaluates to `nil`.

If you want it to have a specific value, you need to actually assign it one: you defined an attribute writer method, but you never call it:

```ruby
foo_class.number = 4
```

Now, the instance variable `@number` of `foo_class` is initialized to `4`.

If you don't want to force your users to remember to initialize the instance variable themselves, you can use an *initializer method*. Note that initializer methods are nothing special, they are methods just like any other method.

However, most objects are created by calling the `Class#new` factory method, which looks something like this:

```ruby
class Class
  def new(...)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(...)
    obj
  end
end
```

As you can see, the default implementation of `Class#new` calls an instance method called `initialize` on the newly created instance, which means you can customize the initialization by overriding `#initialize`:

```ruby
class FooClass
  @number = 3

  attr_accessor :number

  def initialize
    self.number = 4
  end
end
```

Now, it is guaranteed that the instance variable `@number` of any instance of `FooClass` will always be initialized to `4` (at least when users use the default `Class#new` factory method).

Comment: It couldn't have been clearer than this! Many thanks!

Comment: Rule #1 of understanding Ruby: think about what the object is at this place in the code. Rule #1.a of understanding Ruby when you come from languages such as Java, C++, or C#: don't forget that when we say "Everything is an object", we mean it. Modules and classes are objects as well. So, you had the right instance variable but the wrong object.